# how to delete particular row in table view and edit that custom cell details

Tags: ios

how to delete particular row in table view in Xcode.
when we can delete one particular row in table view.
and also edit that custom cell objects in another view

Comment: possible duplicate of [change Table to Edit mode and delete Rows inside a normal ViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148229/change-table-to-edit-mode-and-delete-rows-inside-a-normal-viewcontroller)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`

You should read the [UITableView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Editions are done with the [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).